# Difference between checkValidity & validity

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I've noticed there are 2 ways for an input element validation:

1. `element.checkValidity()`.
2. `element.validity.valid`.

I understand that `validity` is an object while `checkValidity` is a function but I don't understand when should I use either one of them and what is the key difference between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`HTMLSelectElement.checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity):

> The `HTMLSelectElement.checkValidity()` method checks whether the element has any constraints and whether it satisfies them. **If the element fails its constraints, the browser fires a cancelable invalid event at the element**, and then returns false.

[`ValidityState.valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState):

> Is a Boolean indicating the element meets all constraint validations, and is therefore considered to be valid.

So the main difference is that `checkValidity()` will *also* fire an "invalid" event. If you just want to know whether the value is valid, use `ValidityState.valid`. But if you want to change the form state to invalid, use `checkValidity()`.

Comment: and which is the difference between "checkValidity" and "reportValidity"?

Comment: @jon_eldiablo it seems that both updates the input.validity object, but only reportValidity shows the error on screen, possibly with additional a11y outputs. The message disappears with a click and/or after a timeout. It does not appear the error changes the DOM.